# Set a value to a 2 strings based on the conditions using stream. Convert for-loop to streams

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I am new to java streams. Trying to set 2 values based on a condition inside Java streams. I tried experimenting. Probably doing something wrong. Any suggestion is welcome.

The working code which i want to convert to streams is :

```
String D1 = "";
String D2 = "";

for(int i = 0; i < loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters().length; i++){
    if(loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters()[i].getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(RapFilter.D1)){
        D1 = loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters()[i].getValue();
    } else if(loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters()[i].getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(RapFilter.D2)){
        D2 = loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters()[i].getValue();
    }
}
```

My attempt :

```
String D1  = Arrays.stream(loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters())
    .filter(rgp-> rgp.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(RapFilter.D1))
    .findFirst()
    .map(rgp->rgp.getValue()) //not sure how to set D2
    .orElse("");
```

Comment: I think your current implementation is fine, no need to use stream here, still you need do the same operation for D2

Comment: I’d stay with the loop, but take benefit from local variables. There is no need to repeat expressions like `loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters()[i]` four times. Since this is an array, use a for-each loop `for(var p: loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters()) { String key = p.getKey(); if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(RapFilter.D1)) D1 = p.getValue(); else if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(RapFilter.D2)) D2 = p.getValue(); }` Before Java 10, you have to replace `var` with the actual element type of the array. But it’s still better than repeating the long expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group the entities by the key. Let's suppose the method call `loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters()` returns `List<Parameter>` object (you should make clear with what objects you work with).

Here is a solution:

```
List<Parameter> parameters = loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters();
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(parameters )
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            parameter -> parameter.getKey(), 
            Collectors.reducing("UNKNOWN", parameter -> parameter.getValue(), (s1, s2) -> s2)));

String D1 = map.get(RapFilter.D1);
String D2 = map.get(RapFilter.D2);
```

Let's break this down:

1. The first step is to create `Map<String, List<Parameter>>` map with the key `Parameter.getKey()`.

   ```
   List<Parameter> parameters = loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters();
   Map<String, List<Parameter>> map = Arrays.stream(parameters)   // Stream<Parameter>
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(                        // Map<String, List<Parameter>>
                    parameter -> parameter.getKey()));            // .. with this key
   ```
2. Since you want the last found value matching the key from the `List<Parameter>`, you can find it with reducing elements into the last one using another downstream collector `Collectors.reducing`:

   ```
   List<Parameter> parameters = loadReportTableExt.getReportGenerationParameters();
   Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(parameters)            // Stream<Parameter>
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(                        // Map<String, String>
                   parameter -> parameter.getKey(),               // .. with this key
                   Collectors.reducing(                           // .. value from List<Parameter>
                           "UNKNOWN",                             // .... default value
                           parameter -> parameter.getValue(),     // .... real found value
                           (s1, s2) -> s2)));                     // .... the last one
   ```
3. The last step is to extract the value from the created `map`:

   ```
   String D1 = map.get(RapFilter.D1);
   String D2 = map.get(RapFilter.D2);
   ```

I have not tested the solution and it might require some modifications including renaming the class `Parameter` since I made it up. However, I hope you get the idea and something you can start at.

Note the following:

- The `"UNKNOWN"` is used as a default value if the list is empty (should not happen).
- `map.get(RapFilter.D1);` might return `null` if the key is not present.